# Python trying to get paragraph from weather website

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to python 2.7 but I am trying to get a simple paragraph from a website but python outputs []. I've managed to extract numbers but not text.

Any help would be great, thanks.

```
import urllib
import re

HTML_File = urllib.urlopen("http://uk.weather.com/weather/10day/New+Romney+KEN+United+Kingdom+UKXX1121:1:UK")
HTML_Text = HTML_File.read()

LastUpdate_Pattern = re.compile('<div class="wx-24hour-title"> <h2>New Romney 10-Day Forecast</h2> <p class="wx-timestamp"> (.*?) </p>')

LastUpdate = re.findall(LastUpdate_Pattern, HTML_Text)

print LastUpdate
```

Comment: There are libraries to make this much easier for you. Have a look at [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [`beautifulsoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: Okay I will do, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BeautifulSoup`

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HTML_File = urllib.urlopen("http://uk.weather.com/weather/10day/New+Romney+KEN+United+Kingdom+UKXX1121:1:UK")
HTML_Text = HTML_File.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML_Text, 'html.parser')

print soup.select('.wx-timestamp')[0].text
```

Output:

```
Updated:

last updated about 20 minutes ago
```

Comment: Thank you :) I will start using that now.